# How to find a certain date after another given date in using php?

Tags: php, date

How can I find the next occurrence of a fixed date after another date?

For example:

I need to find when April 1 is

if the date I have is 2013-02-28 I need to return 2013-04-01

if the date I have is 2013-05-01 I need to return 2014-04-01

Is there a quick way to do this?

**update**

Relative date formats do not work correctly in php 5.3.3 
This is what I would up doing instead:

```
function aprilFoolsDay($datein,$format){

    $date = new DateTime($datein);

    $year = $date->format("Y");

    $april = new DateTime($year.'-04-01');

    if($date > $april){

        $april = new DateTime(($year + 1).'-04-01');

    }

    return $april->format($format);

}


echo aprilFoolsDay('2011-05-28','Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use relative time formats to get to the date you seek:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2013-02-28');
$date2 = clone $date1;
$date2->modify('First day of  April');
if ($date2 < $date1) {
    $date2->modify('+1 year');
}
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d');

$date1 = new DateTime('2014-05-01');
$date2 = clone $date1;
$date2->modify('First day of  April');
if ($date2 < $date1) {
    $date2->modify('+1 year');
}
echo $date2->format('Y-m-d');
```

Output:

```
2013-04-01
2015-04-01
```

Here's a reusable function:

```
echo getNextAprilFirst('2013-02-28');
echo getNextAprilFirst('2014-05-01');

function getNextAprilFirst($date) {
    $date1 = new DateTime($date);
    $date2 = clone $date1;
    $date2->modify('First day of  April');
    if ($date2 < $date1) {
        $date2->modify('+1 year');
    }
    return $date2->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Output:

```
2013-04-01
2015-04-01
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/keqhva)

Comment: this doesn't work. 2nd example goes backwards in time. OP wanted *next* occurance

Comment: Curious, why clone an existing object & modify instead of a new object with the correct date to begin with?

Comment: Because we don't know what year that date will be. If we just use `'First day of  April'` we'll always get this year.

Comment: .. but not necessary if you just compare month instead of date as a whole

Comment: does not seem to work at all, are relative time formats available in php 5.3?

Comment: Yes. This should work on PHP 5.3. It does [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Wt69L1) (you can see the version in the top right corner). Do you get errors?

Comment: no errors, I'm just 'echo $date2->format('Y-m-d');' after the modify & it shows the original date '2013-02-28' ~ unmodified. Tried case in the relative statement, even tried reading the relative data php docs!

Comment: Here's a [link showing it working in PHP 5.3](http://3v4l.org/hgMbK). Looks like in PHP 5.3.0 - 5.3.5 it is broken due to a bug in `DateTime::modify()`. I guess check to see what minor version of PHP you are running as that may be the issue.

Comment: yea - look at output for 5.3.0 - 5.3.5, that's what I am seeing - I'm using php 5.3.3 - too bad, this was a really neat solution :(

Comment: That is a shame. `DateTime` is powerful and you can't use one of its most useful features. I guess try @bansi's solution as this bug shouldn't affect `strtotime()`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think [Relative Format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) supports something like "next april" (this example certainly doesn't work), but you can do this:

```
$date = new DateTime("2013-05-01");
$target_date = new DateTime("April 1");
$date->modify(
  $target_date->format("m/d"). 
  (($date->format('m')>$target_date->format('m'))?"+1 year":'')
);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d"); // output: 2014-04-01
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/**
 * @param $date string of date
 * @return unix time of april fools
 */
function getNextAprilFoolsOfYear($date) {
    // unix time for date
    $unixdate = strtotime($date);

    $year = date('Y', $unixdate);

    $currentyearfools = strtotime($year . '-04-01');

    // check if current date is past this year april fools or not
    if ($unixdate < $currentyearfools) {
        // if not pass yet
        return $currentyearfools;
    } else {
        return strtotime(($year + 1) . '-04-01');
    }
}

echo date('Y-m-d', getAprilFoolsOfYear('2014-01-01'));
echo '<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d', getNextAprilFoolsOfYear('2014-05-01'));
```

Output:

```
2014-04-01
2015-04-01
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime). Note this function is timezone aware.

> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a
>   time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use
>   different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended. See
>   date_default_timezone_get() on the various ways to define the default
>   time zone.

```
$dtstr = '2013-03-28';
$dtmonth = date("m",strtotime($dtstr));
$dtyear = date("Y",strtotime($dtstr));
$dtyear = $dtmonth<4?$dtyear:$dtyear+1;
$dt = strtotime('1 April ' . $dtyear);
echo date("Y-m-d",$dt);
```